# Change detection в Angular

Tags: angular2

Подскажите, почему происходят changes в компоненте в котором

changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

В компоненте используется директива в которой код:

@HostListener('mouseover') mouseOver(event: Event){

```
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'active')
}
```

ведь никакие Input в компоненте не меняются

Comment: здесь добавляется класс к элементу, это не имеет отношения к CD

Comment: шаблон перерисовывается когда отрабатывает директива, вопрос, почему?

Comment: для того чтобы изучать онпуш нужно знать как работают зоны и как angular управляет асинхронностью, не зная этого - это пустая трата времени

Comment: та вроде в курсе что зона делает, на 3 события. события Ui, timer, xhr, но ведь OnPush по умолчанию на Input реагирует?

Comment: > `та вроде в курсе что зона делает, на 3 события. события Ui, timer, xhr` - нет, не знаете :)))